# Cordova application for iOS not showing images loaded through ajax

Tags: jquery, ios, ajax, jquery-mobile, cordova

I've got this Cordova application that loads the pages from an external url. I've removed the cordova scripts and relied mostly on jquery mobile, continuing to develop it like a mobile website, on a windows pc with firefox.
One page in the website must load some products and display them in a list, with images and names. All the product data is loaded through AJAX, the images are sent as names (10.jpg) and i simply append some img tags to the list, with a certain src.
Everything works fine in Firefox, but when i build the app in Xcode to see it in the simulator (iOS 6.1), blue question marks appear instead of images.
This is the code that manages the result received through ajax:

```
success: function(result) {
        var vs = eval(result);
        var products = vs['products'];
        for(var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
            $(".ui-page-active #listing").append('<div class="prodwrapper"><img class="pimg" src="/images/'+products[i].pimg+'" border="0" alt="" /><div class="pname"><a href="product.php?id='+products[i].prodid+'">'+products[i].prodname+'</a></div><div class="pdetails"><div class="paddcommbtn"><a href="">add comments</a></div><div class="preadbtn"><a href="">read</a></div><div class="pprice">$'+products[i].prodprice+'</div></div></div>');
        }
    }
```

So, the question is simple:
What am i doing wrong, where is my mistake, what should i do to avoid the problem ?
I must mention that the ajax requests work kind of slow, too, in the simulator.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is `#listing` a `ul` with `data-role set to `listview`?

Comment: `#listing` is a `div`. Would making it a list with `data-role` set to `listview` change things ? I forgot to mention that this is my first app using these techniques, so mistakes like this can appear.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is obvious.

If you are loading pages from a remote source that would mean your images are also placed somewhere at a remote source but you are trying to show images like they are part of your cordova application.

Basically this location:

```
/images/'+products[i].pimg+'
```

points to cordova assets/images directory and you don't want that. You want to point them to your remote source.

When you use Firefox your application is accessed directly, but this case is different, cordova application acts as a proxy for your mobile content and at a same time it also acts as a web server. Every relative link will be handled as a location found inside a cordova assets directory.

Comment: I also used the full URL for the images, the `src` was `http://www.****.com/images/+products[i].pimg` and still the photos did not show.
But thanks for the other details, i will keep that in mind.

Comment: When i first created the script that loaded and appended the images, the links were fully written. And the images did not show up. If it was ok, i would not have modified it to the version written in my question.

Comment: But did that full links work on its own? Did you use that link and executed it inside a browser?

Comment: Sure did. It is the same link that is used on the main site. And also when i tested it in Firefox, everything worked fine.